# Why doesn't the forward scattered wave interfere destructively to cancel in a dielectric material?

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation

Setup: incident light enters a dielectric material and transmitted light leaves the material with a phase shift which depends on the frequency of incoming light and physical characteristic of dipoles within dielectric i.e. how close the incident frequency is to resonant frequency of dipole. This transmitted light is the vector sum of incident field and the field scattered by dipoles with the material.

Q:Why doesn't the forward scattered wave in dielectric material cancel due to destructive interference? The reason that the backward and lateral scattered waves cancel is because there always exists a dipole half a wavelength away from every other dipole whose scattered waves destructively interfere, so why isn't this logic applicable in the forward direction?

Comment: You wrote: "The reason that the backward and lateral scattered waves cancel is because there always exists a dipole half a wavelength away from every other dipole whose scattered waves destructively interfere". But for two waves to cancel you need 3 things: parallel propagation, amplitude equality and opposite phases. A single scattering dipole can contribute to only one of those at any given time, so how does having array of those apply to your premise of total cancelation?

Comment: Consider 2 dipoles half a wavelength apart on the y axis. As an incident wave-front hits the dipoles from the left (moving from x<0 to x>0), the dipoles start oscillating in the z direction, out of and into the page. These oscillations generate a secondary wave, i.e. a scattered wave, whose circular wave-fronts spread out from the dipole centre. Assuming no amplitude decay over a distance of half a wavelength, the 2 scattered waves will destructively interfere because they are half a wavelength apart in space.